# How much in revenue did NASA report for the US fiscal 2016?

Tags: cost, operations

In US dollars, how much revenue did NASA project in 2015 for its fiscal 2016 budget and what percentage was manifested during or before Q4 2016?

The answer may include departmental, management or contract based revenue, grants, etc.